# mvvmcross network plugin POST POCO

Tags: rest, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an mvvmcross application using WebAPI, I included the network plugin, with this I can make simple requests and get POCO objects. However, I've been trying to POST POCO to the WebAPI with little success. How would I do this? I've tried different kinds of RestRequests, but they didn't work. The furthest I got is using MvxWwwFormRestRequest, in this case the WebAPI's post got a poco instance, but all the properties were null.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the network plugin is quite young - please do consider it 'alpha'

i produced an initial release in the hope others would join in... But sadly the others found other distractions - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/240

For sending a json object to the server, use a POST request with https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/MvxJsonRestRequest.cs

I believe this json post works, but overall more dev and testing is undoubtedly still needed on this plugin.

Comment: I'll start to use this plugin... I'll be running some tests and will give my contribution if needed.